# Jquery simple datepicker will not show - code started working mysteriously after copied over into another file WHAT IS GOING ON

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Update: OK I missed the jquery-ui.js and .css from the example code below but even with those included, the datepicker did not work, BUT...

I created a new php file and started to copy over the code bits by bits to try and figure out what was causing the problem and it turns out, nothing was... I don't understand what the actual f. is happening here but I copied the exact code from the beginning to the end to a freshly created php file and it worked.

Then, the same thing happened with my collapsible nav bar.. it didn't expand on the index page, worked fine on others, the nav bar is php included on all pages. Same thing, I made a copy of another page that it worked on, overwrote it with exact code from the index page, and it worked!!!

Can anyone explain this?

---

New to Jquery, having tried a number of different bits of code for a simple jquery datepicker, I could not get one of them work, the datepicker would not show.

I've also tried later versions of bootstrap(4.5.0) and jquery(3.5.1) which made no difference.

Am I missing something?
Below is the latest one I've tried. When I click on the glyphicon nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>untitled</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <div class="form-group">     
          <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy">
            <div class="input-group-addon" >
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
          </div>             
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {    
 $('.input-group.date').datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"}); 
  });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't `datepicker` jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Access .date,  use date class in input field and it should work.